# How to store the current buffer filename with cursor position to register using neovim Lua API?

Tags: lua, neovim

In vim I can use `getcurpos()` and `expand('%:t')`, but how does this work in lua? The solution should ideally only use the neovim api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the neovim api:

```lua
function Fcolumn_noplenary()
  local fname = vim.fn.expand('%:t')
  local line_col_pair = vim.api.nvim_win_get_cursor(0) -- row is 1, column is 0 indexed
  local fnamecol = fname .. ':' .. tostring(line_col_pair[1]) .. ':' .. tostring(line_col_pair[2])
  vim.fn.setreg('+', fnamecol) -- register + has filename:row:column
end
```

And with [plenary](https://github.com/nvim-lua/plenary.nvim):

```lua
function Fcolumn_plenary()
  local Path = require "plenary.path"
  local path = Path.path
  local fileAbs = vim.api.nvim_buf_get_name(0)
  local p = Path:new fileAbs
  local fname = p.filename 
  local line_col_pair = vim.api.nvim_win_get_cursor(0) -- row is 1, column is 0 indexed
  local fnamecol = fname .. ':' .. tostring(line_col_pair[1]) .. ':' .. tostring(line_col_pair[2])
  vim.fn.setreg('+', fnamecol) -- register + has filename:row:column
end
```

As of neovim 0.8, there is vim.fs which only leaves setting the register with vimscript (vim.fn) and no external dependencies:

```lua
function Fcolumn():
  local fileAbs = vim.api.nvim_buf_get_name(0)
  local fname = vim.fs.basename(fileAbs)
  local line_col_pair = vim.api.nvim_win_get_cursor(0) -- row is 1, column is 0 indexed
  local fnamecol = fname .. ':' .. tostring(line_col_pair[1]) .. ':' .. tostring(line_col_pair[2])
  vim.fn.setreg('+', fnamecol) -- register + has filename:row:column
end
```